# Autofac with service, repository and web api

Tags: asp.net, autofac

Autofac registers Service with IService, and Service is using repository for logic

```
        builder.Register(c => new Service(IServiceRepository)).As<IService>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

When I register repository like this

```
    builder.Register(c => new Repository(DbContext)).As<IRepository>()
        .InstancePerRequest();
```

Autofac doesn't register it, why?

Service is using IServiceRepository in constructor and Repository is using DbContext in his constructor, Autofac registers Service well with IService, but not with Repository

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is new to autofac solution is create modules for service and repository in separate files with RegisterType and use RegisterAssemblyModules to connect/register them in Startup